# Two-way encryption in PostgreSQL version 9.1 database

Tags: postgresql, encryption

What is the process of two-way encryption of data in PostgreSQL database version 9.1 using built-in functions?

Comment: Did you have a look at pgcrypto? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL's built-in two-way encryption functions are documented [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html). The functions that come in the encrypt/decrypt pairs are the two-way encryption options.